# how to convert mouse move event into mouse scroll/drag event

Tags: qt, events, mouse

My app requires me to use multiple mouse and when user moves a particular mouse then OS should give back the mouse drag/scroll event. I want to implement this using Qt 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is

> QWidget::setMouseTracking ( true );
>
> that should invoke QWidget::mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
>   whenever your mouse moves
>
> then you can handle the event as you want.

If you are looking for general drag event then Qt already handles mouse events
QWidget::dragEnterEvent ( QDragEnterEvent * event )
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#dragEnterEvent

Comment: I know that qt has its own mousemove event. My app already contains mousemove and mousedrag handlers. My problem is that I have a trackball mouse which is expected to behave as the drag/scroll works in normal system mouse. What I want is a wrapper around the trackball mouse events so that it works as mouse drag. I am working on windows XP.

Comment: @Kashish: Does Qt invoke mouseMoveEvent when you do something with the trackball mouse?

Comment: Hi Blueskin, thankyou for your response and interest. The trackball mouse is a serial device connected to COM1 port, doesnt have a wheel (for drag) and is giving me inputs in dX and dY only. I want to emit a QWheel event which will convert my dx into event->delta(). Is there a way to convert dX( amount of ball movement at a time from static position) to a QWheelEvent.